# C# Associating DatePicker with a TimePicker

Tags: c#, datepicker, timepicker

I was wondering if there is a way to associate two different dateTimePickers.

For example, I have one dateTimePicker that is set for my Pick Up Date and lets the user select a date, and I have a second one that is set for a Pick Up Time and lets the user select a time. How would I go about linking those two together? Say the user picks February 26th, 2014 for pick up date and 12:00PM for the time so their pick up date would read as February 26th, 2014 @ 12:00PM.

Also, suppose I want to add two more dateTimePickers for a drop off date and time, can I compare the two dates and times to get the number of hours between the two?

UPDATE: So far this is the code I have.

```
DateTime pickUpDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
DateTime dropOffDate = dateTimePicker2.Value.Date;
int newDate = Convert.ToInt32(dropOffDate.Hour);
int hours = (int)Math.Round((dropOffDate - pickUpDate).TotalHours);
```

and that will give me 24 or 48 hours for a one and two day difference.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by associate, but you can always take the values from both and put them together in javascript or code behind

Comment: What have you got so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about `DateTime pickupTime = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.AddHours(dateTimePicker2.Value.Hour);`?

Then you can do similar with dropoffTime, then do `TimeSpan duration = dropoffTime - pickupTime;`

Comment: Thanks! That got me in the right direction. 

int hours = (int)Math.Round((dropOffTime - pickUpTime).TotalHours);

Is what I used for the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

I just linked them by setting the other control's value property when the first control is changed.

i.e.

```
    private void datePicker_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timePicker.Value = datePicker.Value;
        selectedTimeUtc.Text = timePicker.Value.ToString();           
    }

    private void timePicker_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        datePicker.Value = timePicker.Value;
        selectedTimeUtc.Text = timePicker.Value.ToString();           
    }
```

Hope this helps,

Cheers,

Kevin